# Azure Function is not working on timer from Azure

Tags: python, sql, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that runs a Python script. The Python script makes an API request, get information, and inputs that information into a SQL database and right now is configured to run every hour based on my chron expression shown by my function.json:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 0 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

My function works 100% of the time locally and when I deploy the function there are no issues. When my timer goes off, it says success but when I check the SQL database, there are no updates.

The weird thing is, sometimes the function does work when I go to the Code + Test tab in Azure and run it, but most times it just says it ran and there are no updates. For instance, I just ran it 4 times manually from Code + Test in Azure, the first 2 updated the SQL database and had runtimes of 115ms and 75ms, and the last 2 did not update the SQL database (yet said success), and had runtimes of 20ms and 50ms.

I am unsure what is the issue but I will show some more of my code below.

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

settings.json:

```
{
    "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
    "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
    "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~4",
    "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```

Comment: `host.json` and `settings.json` are not your codes, they are generated code by default. Show the logic how you written the code for updating the SQL DB Table.

Comment: This is not a common problem. Read  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide some more codes to recurrence problem.